# Error while accessing DAX aws from localhost client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Getting Error while accessing DAX AWS from localhost client

Error:

EVERE: caught exception during cluster refresh: java.io.IOException: failed to configure cluster endpoints from hosts: [daxcluster*:8111]
java.io.IOException: failed to configure cluster endpoints from hosts:

**Sample test code**

```
public static String clientEndPoint = "*.amazonaws.com:8111";

DynamoDB getDynamoDBClient() {
    System.out.println("Creating a DynamoDB client");
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    return new DynamoDB(client);
}
static DynamoDB getDaxClient(String daxEndpoint) {
    ClientConfig daxConfig = new ClientConfig().withEndpoints(daxEndpoint);
    daxConfig.setRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1.getName());
    AmazonDaxClient client = new ClusterDaxClient(daxConfig);
    DynamoDB docClient = new DynamoDB(client);
    return docClient;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    DynamoDB client = getDaxClient(clientEndPoint);
    Table table = client.getTable("dev.Users");
    Item fa = table.getItem(new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("userid", "tf@gmail.com"));
    System.out.println(fa);

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access DAX clusters from local? Can you show the code?

Comment: @notionquest  i have put the code in above post .

Comment: This may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928457/getting-failed-to-configure-cluster-endpoints-error-when-using-dax-with-dynamodb. Please check whether the inbound traffic on TCP port 8111 has required privilege.

Answer (score 2):

A DAX cluster runs within your VPC. To connect from your laptop to the DAX cluster, you need to VPN into your VPC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html

Answer (score 2):

**Answer: DAX is only supported within VPC**

I faced this same issue myself and found out the hard way.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html

> Usage Notes For a list of AWS regions where DAX is available, refer to
>   https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing.
>
> DAX supports applications written in Java, Node.js, .Python and .NET,
>   using AWS-provided clients for those programming languages.
>
> DAX does not support Transport Layer Security (TLS).
>
> **DAX is only available for the EC2-VPC platform.** (There is no support
>   for the EC2-Classic platform.)
>
> DAX clusters maintain metadata about the attribute names of items they
>   store, and that metadata is maintained indefinitely (even after the
>   item has expired or been evicted from the cache). Applications that
>   use an unbounded number of attribute names can, over time, cause
>   memory exhaustion in the DAX cluster. This limitation applies only to
>   top-level attribute names, not nested attribute names. Examples of
>   problematic top-level attribute names include timestamps, UUIDs, and
>   session IDs.
>
> Note that this limitation only applies to attribute names, not their
>   values. Items like this are not a problem: